# .Net Msmq How to find conflicts in Msmq

Tags: c#

I have one Msmq Queue which contain value
 like 1,2,3,4. Before inserting other values in my Msmq I check the conflict in Msmq means when I insert 1 it is not inserted in to Msmq. This is how I achieve the check:

I read the message from Msmq and then check with my newly inserted value

but problem is when I read  this message from Msmq then first message is deleted from Msmq. I don't want this. Is their another way for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to view the contents of a message on MSMQ without removing it, use Peek() or one of its overloads:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/829zyck7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This has the potential to get messy very quickly; a better solution might be to add the item to the queue irrespective of whether it already exists and design the recieving end such that it ignores duplicate messages.